# How to position Kivy Popup with absolute coordinate?

Tags: python, popup, kivy

How do you disable relative position for a Kivy Popup object? For example, how would you define absolute `pos` for this example?:

```
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
popup = Popup(title='Test popup', content=Label(text='Hello world'),
              size_hint=(None, None), 
              #pos_hint=None, pos_hint=(None, None), pos_hint={}, 
              size=(200,200), pos=(10, 10))
popup.open()
```

Notice if the `pos_hint` attempts are uncommented, it fails either because `pos_hint` mustn't be null, cannot be a tuple, or simply has no effect (the popup is always centered vertically and horizontally). Notice also that the custom size *does* work.

Answer (score 1):

Since pos_hint works well you can always do: ("10.0" is the absolute coordinate )

```
    popup = Popup(title='Test popup', content=Label(text='Hello world'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), 
                  pos_hint={'x': 10.0 / Window.width, 
                            'y':10.0 /  Window.height},  
                  size=(200,200), #pos=(10, 10),

                  )
```

The only problem here is that you'll have to update the pos_hint on a re-size event

Comment: Thanks - this is certainly a good work around. In fact, if there is no way to possibly set absolute position explicitly, I'll mark it as the sol.

Answer (score 0):

pos_hint should be a dict, not a tuple, so probably `pos_hint={}` or `pos_hint=None` will work (but I'm not sure which).

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add my other attempts - some of which as you recommend. Unfortunately these do not work (see updated question).